# How to Download Android studio in i3 processor?

Tags: android-studio

How to download Android Studio in i3 processor?
I am trying to download Android Studio 3.3.1 but the buttons on their page seems to not work, I get no feedback. I tried on multiple browsers.

Please if you are good enough to share the download link.

Comment: what webpage were you trying to download from? ... which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to update your processor anyhow if you will install on i3 your laptop may work slow.

Answer (score 0):

may be change your browser and try this link:

https://developer.android.com/studio